# Densest k subgraph problem for outerplanar graphs?

Tags: graph-theory, graph-algorithms, planar-graphs

The *densest k subgraph problem* aims to find a subgraph $H$ of a graph $G$ with exactly $k$ vertices that maximizes the number of edges $|E(H)|$.

Does anyone know if there exists a polynomial-time algorithm for this problem under the restriction that $G$ is outerplanar? (Note: I am specifically asking for an algorithm, not a PTAS, and I want $G$ to be outerplanar, not $b$-outerplanar for some $b > 1$).

Comment: Is $k$ a constant, or is it given as part of the input?

Comment: Also, since $|V(H)|$ is fixed, you are simply maximizing $|E(H)|$, right?

Comment: This can be done in polynomial time by dynamic programming.

Comment: In my view densest-k-subgraph is not particularly interesting for "hereditarily sparse" graphs.

Comment: @ChandraChekuri Can you explain a bit more what you mean by this? First, what exactly is a "hereditarily sparse" graph? Does this include e.g. graphs with low degeneracy? Because in these, Densest-k-Subgraph does have manyapplications, so it is at least interesting from an application point of view.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek $k$ is a constant, and yes you are correct, the goal is to maximize $|E(H)|$.

Comment: Well, if $k$ is constant, you don’t need any sophisticated approach, you can do it in polynomial time $O(n^k)$ on arbitrary graphs by brute force enumeration.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It can be solved in linear time in an even more general class of graphs: As shown in

N. Bourgeois, A. Giannakos, G. Lucarelli, I. Milis, V.T. Paschos
Exact and approximation algorithms for densest $k$-subgraph
WALCOM’13, LNCS, vol. 7748, Springer-Verlag (2013), pp. 114-125

the Densest-$k$-Subgraph problem can be solved in $O(2^{\mathrm{tw}(G)}\cdot k \cdot ((\mathrm{tw}(G)^2)+k)\cdot |X|)$ time when a tree decomposition $(X,T)$ of the input graph $G$ is given. Since outerplanar graphs have treewidth at most two, the Densest-$k$-Subgraph can be solved in $O(k^2 n)$ time on outerplanar graphs with $n$ vertices.